# How to say "I look forward to it"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, correspondance

I have an email from a supplier letting me know when something is going to be made available. I would like to thank them and say "I look forward to it". How would you say this in French?

Comment: Ce n'est pas un site de traduction. Pour une traduction rapide : http://www.reverso.net/translationresults.aspx?lang=FR&direction=anglais-francais ; pour une traduction en tenant compte du contexte : http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=I+look+forward+to+it -- Il existe beaucoup d'autres sites !

Comment: Just a comment from a non-native speaker, but although the idiomatic “Au plaisir (de vous revoir)” is only for expressing that you’re “looking forward to see a person”, I have also seen/heard the following variation of it used (perhaps incorrectly) for places and things: “Au plaisir de la/le voir en vrai [bientôt].”

Comment: A very general comment on all of the suggested answers: make very sure that your expression cannot be be misconstrued as ironic or sarcastic, especially with "voir ça" (j'ai hâte de voir ça, je suis impatient de voir ça) or too aggressive (j'attends avec impatience, je suis pressé)

Answer (score 8):

In this case, "I'm looking forward to it" could also mean "I can't wait to see it". It is the way it will be translated into French, expressing the "I'm excited" idea, but in a more formal way. Here are a few examples of correct and formal translations :

> Je suis pressé de voir ça

or

> J'ai hâte de voir ça

or even

> Je suis emballé par ça ! (this is quite unformal, to be honest.)

**EDIT : **
As Stéphane pointed in the comments, I suggest another, way more formal way to express this.

> Je me réjouis d'avance

Where "Je me réjouis" expresses happiness, and "d'avance" refers to the future, when you get thing you are actually waiting for.

Comment: All of these are informal. I would never use any in a professional context.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I added a more formal way to say this ;) We probably don't work in the same places but where I work, I have no problem saying "Je suis pressé de voir ça" to anyone, even my boss.

Comment: Much better. But in general one has to be careful, because such translations only work in very specific contexts like this one.

Comment: I would simply say "J'ai hâte", because "J'ai hâte de voir ça" is often used in a sarcastic manner, meaning it's not likely whatever it is will ever be seen.

Answer (score 3):

In a formal way you can say something like:

> "dans l'attente de votre réponse veuillez agréer mes salutations les plus respectueuses"

it means : I look forward to hearing from you

Comment: This is extremely formal and nice :) it is so formal it made me laugh. In a nice way. Good approach.

Answer (score 2):

> Je l'anticipe.

This is how I would say "I am looking forward to it" in French.

Answer (score 1):

As a non-native speaker, I would say..Je serais vraiment content de le reçevoir. or ça sera mon plaisir de le recevoir. This means... I'll really be glad to receive/get it.  It will be a pleasure to receive it. Looking forward to something suggests the future... Also, I believe that a French teacher teaching everyday French said that something like ..Je l'attend avec impatience! or Je suis impatient de le reçevoir/voir Both suggest a sense of anxiously (in a good way; not worried) awaiting something/to receive/see something...I hope a native speaker can clear this up for us. Very interesting site!..

Comment: Welcome to French Language. Formatting and using the proper punctuation helps readability.  You can edit your answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

[**Source: Handbook of Commercial French (G. Geoghegan and G. Gonthier Geoghegan).**](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8OoVAQAAMAAJ&q=handbook%20of%20commercial%20french%20routledge&dq=handbook%20of%20commercial%20french%20routledge&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi50ov1u6vbAhUpBcAKHZQ0DWUQ6AEIKDAA)

Apparently out of print.

English letter

(...)

> We are sure you will be satisfied with the quality of our products and
> look forward to receiving further orders.

French version

(...)

> Dans l'espoir que vous apprécierez la qualité de nos produits et que
> nous aurons l'occasion de traiter à nouveau avec vous, nous vous
> prions de recevoir, cher Monsieur, nos sentiments les meilleurs.

Other examples

> I look forward to seeing you while I am in...
>
> Dans l'attente de vous rencontrer au cours de mon séjour à...
>
> I am looking forward to meeting you.
>
> Dans l'attente de vous rencontrer.
>
> We look forward to receiving your reply.
>
> Dans l'attente de votre réponse.

Answer (score 0):

> ...a supplier letting me know when something is going to be made
> available.
>
> **Cette perspective m'enchante.** [à partir d'une [suggestion](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/look/592904#592915) de Larousse en ligne ang.-fr.]

[*Perspective*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/perspective) (un des sens au figuré) : « Événement ou ensemble d'événements futurs envisagés » (Wiktionnaire).

Answer (score -3):

In a non-formal way, you can say this:

> Je vais voir cela

This means that will will look at it, think about it.

---

> J'y songerais

This means that you will think about it, but you are still uncertain.

---

The "less formal" way to say it is:

> Je vais voir cela et je vous tiens au courant

This means that you will think about it and that you will contact him if things happen.

There is no real translation

Comment: I can see Nico's concern only because "thinking about it" does not to me imply excitement (as in OPs looking forward to something) but implies deliberation and unsureness.