# « My/your/his… two cents » en français

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, france

La [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29256/17649) posée en mars 2018 à propos de cette locution  ne résulte  pas exactement en un traitement du même problème, d'autant plus que des traductions qui  sont proposées, comme « c'est … mon avis », ne conviennent pas.

> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents)) Usage [of "my two cents"]
>
> The expression is used to preface a tentative statement of one’s opinion. By deprecating the opinion to follow—suggesting its value is only two cents, a very small amount—the user of the phrase, showing politeness and humility, hopes to lessen the impact of a possibly contentious statement.

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/my+two+cents.html) propose la traduction « mon/ton/son/… grain de sel » deux fois, dont l'une est jugée douteuse ; je pense moi-même que cette traduction n'est pas des meilleures : si la notion de « chose peu importante » se dégage de cette expression—cette connotation semble manquer au TLFi—il ne s'agit pas d'un simple avis, et de  plus, la définition inclut un aspect négatif qui ne serait pas présent dans l'expression anglaise.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grain))  (Mettre, mêler, ajouter) son grain de sel (fam.). Donner son avis sur une chose; **se mêler à une conversation sans y être invité**.
> •  Son rôle dans la maison (...) consistait à compliquer les choses, en voulant y fourrer son grain de sel, pour montrer qu'il était le patron (Montherl., Célibataires,1934, p. 794).

DeepL ne propose rien qui me semble idiomatique  ([« mes deux cents »](https://www.deepl.com/translator?utm_source=lingueefr&utm_medium=linguee&utm_content=banner_translator&il=fr#en/fr/my%20two%20cents)). Il y a aussi « [mes deux sous](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/just+my+two+cents.html) » comme traduction par Linguee, mais cette possibilité n'est pas idiomatique à en juger par le TLFi qui rassemble un nombre important d'expressions précises utilisant « sou » sans mentionner celle-ci. L'une d'elles a un sens très similaire mais en tant que qualificatif pas en tant que la chose elle-même.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sou)) b) Loc. [Avec un adj. numéral cardinal tel que *un, deux, quatre*, pour exprimer une valeur insignifiante]
> − Loc. adj. D'un sou, de deux sous, de quatre sous. De très faible valeur ou de valeur nulle.
> • De 5 à 6 h. du matin quand je fais mes petites philosophies d'un sou, dans mes éternels cahiers sans aucune considération de public, sans vergogne (Valéry,Corresp.[avec G. Fourment], 1925, p. 187).

On peut donc traduire selon le contexte.

- mon apport de deux sous
  ma contribution de deux sous
  mon ajout de deux sous
  mon idée de deux sous
  etc.

Est-ce qu'il serait souhaitable de faire de  « mes deux sous » un idiotisme, ou est-ce que l'on doit trouver suffisant de n'utiliser « un/deux/… sous » qu'en tant que qualificatif (comme dans les traductions supra) ?
Quelles autres possibilités existeraient pour éviter les connotations négatives de la locution « mon/ton/… grain de sel », et si possible ajouter celles afférentes à la politesse que l'on trouve dans le langage source (on peut peut-être considérer cela chose faite dans les solutions « deux sous ») ?

---

*Plus d'explication à propos du fait mentionné dans le texte ci-dessus vis-à-vis de la [question de 2018](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29256/17649) et ses réponses.*

« **C'est juste mon avis** » n'est qu'une réserve afférente à la crédibilité concernant l'auteur d'une contribution à part entière, pas l'évaluation d'une contribution comme étant de peu d'importance en cela qu'elle pourrait être partielle, même quelque peu accessoire.

« **Je dis ça, je dis rien** » ne dit rien, à mon avis ; ce n'est certainement pas le dernier mot.

« **À mon humble avis** » n'est qu'un fragment qui n'a rien à faire dans cette réponse en tant que traduction de « my two cents ».

Comment: Je trouve pourtant la réponse acceptée à la question de 2018 quasi parfaite. Si c'est l'idiomatisme de France métropolitaine ou Belgique qui est recherché, je n'emploierais pas *sou* en tout cas.

Comment: @guillaume31 Je ne peux pas être le seul à décider si une réponse convient à une question, que ce soit ma question ou celle de quelqu'un d'autre. Les critères de la langue sont communs à tous et c'est à vous de décider. *J'ai décidé* pour cette question, mais bien sûr il reste au autres à accepter cette décision ou à la rejeter selon qu'elle semblerait justifiée en considération des standard reconnus ou non.

Comment: Tu est le seul à pouvoir décider si une réponse convient à ta question. C'est le privilège des poseurs de questions de pouvoir accepter une réponse ou pas. Cela dit, je trouve que les réponses de [Greg](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29258/1109) et [Crissy Froth Seapickle](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52632/1109) méritent leurs upvotes. Je dis ça, je dis rien...

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne peux pas être le seul puisque si c'était le cas la décision pourrait ne reposer que sur une opinion, et les opinions sont sévèrement exclues.

Comment: @LPH Pas d'accord avec les critiques formulées sur les 3 propositions de 2018. La première est du "chipotage" qui ne résiste pas face à l'impératif de trouver une formulation idiomatique. Je ne comprends pas l'argument des deux autres. (Tout cela bien sûr si on recherche la formulation la plus idiomatique dans la langue courante comme l'indique la Q. S'il s'agit de coller à l'expression imagée des "cents" du texte original dans une traduction littéraire, c'est un parti pris qui se défend mais c'est une toute autre question.)

Comment: Tu es le seul à pouvoir décider d'accepter une réponse à **tes** questions. Tu n'as pas à justifier ces acceptations qui peuvent donc parfaitement être motivées par l'opinion que tu te fais des réponses, et c'est bien sûr la même chose pour tous les utilisateurs qui posent des questions sur StackExchange. Rien n'interdit non plus à d'autres utilisateurs de remettre en question les réponses acceptées, mais sans grand impact si elles répondent à des utilisateurs ayant quitté le site.

Comment: @jlliagre Qui parle d'accepter une réponse ? La question  c'est savoir si l'on doit demander à un utilisateur de dire si la réponse proposée convient ; ce n'est pas à lui de décider ça tout seul, c'est à vous qui demandez ça de décider en premier et de faire en sorte que le processus de décision continue avec le concours des autres utilisateurs et cet utilisateur en particulier à qui on propose une réponse — On n'a rien à  proposer à ce dernier.

Comment: *Qui parle d'accepter une réponse ?* Toi ! : *Je ne peux pas être le seul à décider si une réponse convient à une question, **que ce soit ma question** ou celle de quelqu'un d'autre.*

Comment: Ce que je retiens c'est qu'avec des tours spontanés et des mots comme _juste, humble, petit_, ou des mots qui soulignent le simple apport plutôt que la panacée, et le fait de souligner de qui provient l'opinion, on a pas mal tous les outils pour produire le même sens. Comme je n'avais pas lu la réponse de Greg avant de répondre et qu'il y a intersection, je suis satisfait de voir qu'on a des réflexes similaires pour exprimer l'équivalent.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que c'est ce vote négatif ? Une réponse à 40 points mais la question est mauvaise ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Est-ce que « juste mes deux centimes » est une traduction correcte pour « just my two cents »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29256/est-ce-que-juste-mes-deux-centimes-est-une-traduction-correcte-pour-just-m)

Comment: @livresque Can't you tell by my question that, , as I see the problem,  it doesn't?

Comment: J’aurais bien une proposition de réponse « à deux balles » à la question posée, un peu plus familière.

Comment: @v.nivuahc N'hésite pas à ajouter une réponse...

Answer (score 5):

[*À mon humble avis*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56808) la langue est complète et peut se passer du calque et des histoires de sous. Mais *ça c'est juste moi*. Si on me permet d'*ajouter mon petit grain de sel à la question*, je trouve que de constamment voir l'expression française comme incomplète ou pas aussi expressive que l'anglais relève surtout de l'[ethnocentrisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnocentrisme) ou de la méconnaissance de la langue ([*quot linguas calles, tot homines vales*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_locutions_latines_commen%C3%A7ant_par_Q#Loc-Quot_linguas_calles,_tot_homines_vales)). Parfois l'[emprunt](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/25443/les-emprunts-a-langlais/questions-frequentes-sur-lemprunt-linguistique) ou le calque se justifie par son utilité (mais le phénomène ne saurait être limité à ce seul [critère](https://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/pdf/20170330_politique_emprunt.pdf) et la norme varie dans la francophonie) ; mais rappeler la langue d'origine qui nous serait familière n'est pas utile à la langue française mais bien au locuteur de cette autre langue, il me semble. Ici, l'idée du « my 2 cents » c'est la contribution humble légèrement dépréciée et c'est simplement qu'on a d'autres moyens pour connoter ça au lieu d'une image ou analogie comme celle en anglais.

Ça me rappelle [*pour des prunes*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52571/26366) et là en anglais on avait traduit « for nothing » dans un contexte du genre « on ne t'appelle pas "le bossu" pour des prunes », c'est qu'il y a une raison par antiphrase. L'[origine](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour_des_prunes) de la locution c'est la guerre ou la conquête et on revient avec comme seul tribut un prunier et ses prunes, avec rien relativement vu le contexte. En anglais on a des trucs qui se mangent pour signifier ce qui est trivial dont « [peanuts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peanuts) » par exemple, peut-être qu'on peut dire « I don't want to work for peanuts », pour une [bagatelle](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/bagatelle), pour des [miettes](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/miette), pour rien finalement. Mais je ne pense pas qu'on puisse employer ça pour signifier la raison a contrario (« you're not called "two-bit Tony" for peanuts », bizarre) donc « for nothing » est bon mais est moins imagé que les *prunes*. Devrait-on calquer le français et avoir « for plums » en anglais ? Je ne pense pas, mais ça *c'est mon idée à moi*. *Ça vaut ce que ça vaut*.

Quand on s'était attardé à la traduction de « [in the zone](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52485/26366) », un locuteur d'expérience trouvait que d'être [*concentré*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52487/26366) même sans aucun superlatif convenait alors que j'étais obnubilé par la [possible origine](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/603766/471602) dans *twilight zone*, ô combien plus riche en références, vu l'émission et ses sujets et le surnaturel etc., *pour moi même si ça peut sembler un peu ridicule*.

Et que dire de ma fascination pour « [the shit hit the fan](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/when-the-shit-hits-the-fan.html) », mais c'est simplement que ça a mal viré ou qu'il y a une dispute etc. et quand le locuteur emploie l'expression voit-il l'image de la merde dans le ventilateur au plafond ? Je ne pense pas.

Ou récemment on avait « [a hill to die on](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52625/26366) » et là c'est un cas où il faut voir au cas par cas et on a plusieurs locutions qu'on peut employer selon les contextes, mais a-t-on besoin de mourir sur une colline ? On avait un peu le même genre de défi avec « [bear with me](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52570/26366) ».

Parfois on a une manière différente d'exprimer ça, parfois on a un champ plus ou moins grand d'application d'une locution ou d'une tournure et ça marche dans certains contextes et pas dans d'autres. Parfois on doit scinder des valeurs de certains mots d'une locution pour les transposer dans d'autres mots et avoir une morphologie différente, et là on avait par exemple « [to look forward to](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/18138/26366) » dans un contexte où un fournisseur nous annonce qu'un produit va être désormais disponible et j'ai suggéré « [cette perspective m'enchante](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52478/26366) », où c'est dans le nom *perspective*, l'évènement futur, qu'on trouve le sens de l'adverbe « [forward](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/look-forward-to) », mais ça *c'est juste ma manière à moi de voir les choses et je peux me tromper* ; évidemment que « j'ai hâte » convient aussi...

C'est ma *petite contribution bien personnelle* sur la question...

Comment: D'indéfinition cherchée, claire, à massive expérience personnelle, disconnectée, le lecteur ne peut que se rendre à l'évidence d'un fond soulagé ; cependant, le non expert en illuminations idiosyncratiques ne pourra que regretter le manque de liens informatique vers des sujet « clés », tel que « shit hit the fan », par exemple. À mon avis, liens à ajouter pour  plus de force affirmative.